# how to ssh on a server with sed shell command afterwards

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, sed

I'm trying to shh on a server and execute a sed command afterwards.
Sadly I get a weird error.

If i run this command it works

```
sed -f <(printf "s/${DOMAIN}\.%s/www.&.${FOO}/g\n" ${LANG_KEYS}) ${DB_PATH_TO}${DB_NAME}.sql > ${DB_PATH_TO}new-${DB_NAME}.sql
```

If i however try to run it with a ssh it does not, i believe it is because of the quotes but i'm unsure of how to fix it.

```
ssh ${TARGET_USER}@${TARGET_IP} -i ${TARGET_PRIVATE_KEY} -p ${TARGET_PORT} "
    sed -f <(printf "s/${DOMAIN}\.%s/www.&.${FOO}/g\n" ${LANG_KEYS}) ${DB_PATH_TO}${DB_NAME}.sql > ${DB_PATH_TO}new-${DB_NAME}.sql
"
```

Output:

```
bash: -c: line 1: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `)'
bash: -c: line 2: syntax error: unexpected end of file 
No such file or directory
```

Comment: Are you running the command as part of a a here doc? If you run it as a standard command after ssh, the variables won't expand on the remote server

Comment: I'm running it in on jenkins if that helps. Not sure what you mean with 'here doc'.

Comment: Btw the variables do work. That's no the issue.

Comment: You have a mishmash of quotation marks. Those variables on the second line (`${DOMAIN}`, `${FOO}`, ...) should they be expanded on the local or remote host? Try using single quotes `'` instead of double `"` on the first and third line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try that:

```
ssh ${TARGET_USER}@${TARGET_IP} -i ${TARGET_PRIVATE_KEY} -p ${TARGET_PORT} '
    sed -f <(printf "s/${DOMAIN}\.%s/www.&.${FOO}/g\n" ${LANG_KEYS}) ${DB_PATH_TO}${DB_NAME}.sql > ${DB_PATH_TO}new-${DB_NAME}.sql
'
```

Comment: I mean it kinda solved the one problem. But now it says `/var/www/foobar/sed/test.txt > /var/www/foobar/sed/new-2.txt: No such file or director`

Comment: That's a different problem. Copy the command `sed ...` and run/debug it directly on the server.